# 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im creating a python discord bot, and im trying to create a raw reaction event.

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message.id == 787952259291676673 and payload.emoji.name == "✅":
         print('t')
```

```
File "C:\Users\admin\source\repos\binned\binned\binned.py", line 28, in on_raw_reaction_add
    if payload.message.id == 787952259291676673 and payload.emoji.name == "✅":
AttributeError: 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'message'
```

is the error. ive searched the problem, and none of the solutions fixed it. when i react with ANY emoji, it errors out.

Comment: Error message is clear I guess, you should be using `payload.message_id`. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=raw_reaction#rawreactionactionevent

Answer (score 0):

`on_raw_reaction_add` it's called regardless of the state of the internal message cache. So it's logic that there is not a message attribute, the attribute that you're looking for is `message_id`