# Programming a Discord bot in Python- In on_raw_reaction_add, how do I tell if the message has an image?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want the bot to know when a message is reacted on, and if that message has an image. Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  if payload.message.attatchments[0] != None:
    print("True")
```

When triggered, expect it to print "True", but instead I only get this error: `AttributeError: 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'message'`. I am not sure why this happens, any tips?

**Edit:**
Here's another thing I tried

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
  if message.attatchments[0] != None:
        print("True")
```

It gets the message using the id, and then checks the image. Unfortunately I get an error: `AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'attatchments'`

Answer (score 1):

This question is a duplicate of [another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285658/rawreactionactionevent-object-has-no-attribute-message)

Per the answer there, the attribute that you're looking for is `message_id`

Comment: Okay, so how would I use this to get check the image attachments?

Comment: Try payload.message_id.attachments but I’m not sure

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work either- I updated the question with another thing I tried

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153779/discord-py-attachments